# C++ using only one default argument in function

Tags: c++, function

How can i use only 3rd argument (first and second arguments must be default)?

Like this:

```
double func(const double a = 5, const double b = 6, const double c = 7);

int main()
{
    cout << "A = " << func(10) << endl << endl; //if i do like this, i'm using first argument, but not 3rd.
}
```

Comment: You can't. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Even if you could do this, what would `a` and `b` be defaulted to if you only want to use the third parameter?

Comment: what is so wrong with it? it works in c#, the others are default, only the named parameter is set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ doesn't support what you want to do currently.  However, there are ways around it.  You can use the [Named Parameter Idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Named_Parameter) or boost's [Paremeter library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html).

I recommend the former.  It's clearer, easier to debug, etc...

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this would be to swap the argument order:

```
double func(const double c = 7, const double a = 5, const double b = 6);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could (possibly) use a few wrapper types and overloading, then use the types to name the parameter when calling:

```
struct A { double a; constexpr static double def = 5.0; };
struct B { double b; constexpr static double def = 6.0; };
struct C { double c; constexpr static double def = 7.0; };

double func(double a=A::def, double b=B::def, double c=C::def) { /* whatever */ }

double func(A a) { return func(a.a, B::def, C::def); }
double func(B b) { return func(A::def, b.b, C::def); }
double func(C c) { return func(A::def, B::def, c.c); }

int main()
{
    func(A{3.0});
    func(B{9.0});
    func(C{12.0});
}
```